# CSS partial color percentage value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a percentage value with circles trying to create the image below with code. I'll get the percentage value from the HTML. I'm just not sure how to partially color the circle with css.

[image: Percent progress with color]

```
<div class="meter" data-attr="50%">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

.meter {
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}

<script>
  var circlePrecent = 50%; 
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j8of7yag/

Comment: Read this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j8of7yag/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a basic background color, and cover it with linear gradient. Control the linear gradient's size using `backgroundSize` in js:

```
  background: #AB9E95 linear-gradient(to right, #9F1F63 0%, #9F1F63 100%) no-repeat;
```

Working demo:

```js
colorCircles('65%');

setTimeout(function() {
  colorCircles('37%');
}, 1000);

function colorCircles(percentage) {
  var value = parseInt(percentage, 10);

  var circles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.meter > span'));

  var fullCircles = Math.floor(value / 20);

  var partialCircle = (value % 20) / 20 * 100;

  circles.forEach(function(circle, index) {
    var backgroundSize = '0% 100%';

    if (index < fullCircles) {
      backgroundSize = '100% 100%';
    } else if (index === fullCircles) {
      backgroundSize = partialCircle + '% 100%';
    }

    circle.style.backgroundSize = backgroundSize;
  })
}
```

```css
.meter {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #AB9E95 linear-gradient(to right, #9F1F63 0%, #9F1F63 100%) no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="meter">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect this was exactly what i started coding.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a "hard" gradient like so:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#ffff00 50%,#ffff00 100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element, opposed to `linear-gradient`, which is a really good way, this one works down to IE9 if needed

*Updated based on comment, where it can scale with the circle size and use percent for the background color (4:th has 33.33%)*

```css
.meter span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.meter span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

.meter span:nth-child(3),
.meter span:nth-child(4) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.meter span:nth-child(4):before {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="meter">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this if the precent value is dynamic

Comment: @Phreak Yes, and the border radius is actually unnecessary as the `overflow: hidden` cuts of the pseudo anyway ... updated my answer